# diskutil not showing a particular external hard disk drive

Tags: disk-utility, external-disk

I am facing an odd problem. I have a WD Elements 2TB external hard disk drive, which used to work fine on my MacBook Air running macOS Catalina 10.15.3. The HDD has 4 partitions - one for time machine, two other formatted with Mac OS Extended (Journaled) filesystem and one having FAT32. A problem that I used to face was that the disk would get ejected automatically when the computer went to sleep.

About 3-4 days ago, I discovered that I was unable to open/unmount the FAT32 partition though it was showing on desktop. That day also, probably, the whole disk was improperly ejected at the end as the computer had entered sleep mode. After that, since yesterday, my Mac has completely stopped mounting any partition of the HDD. Neither *System Information* nor `diskutil list` shows the HDD. I have tried restarting the computer while pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> as instructed on the web, but nothings helps.

All four partitions of the HDD are detected on Linux machines and also on another MacBook Air. A Windows machine detects the FAT32 partition. On the other Mac, I ran *First Aid* for each of the partitions and everything came out fine. It’s just that my Mac is not mounting it.

I tried connecting another 1TB Seagate HDD and a 16 GB Kingston pen drive to my Mac and they work as expected. I am at a loss on how to resolve this. It seems just the two together - my Mac and the WD HDD- are not working.

Comment: See if this can help you with troubleshooting: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243559/sometimes-mac-doesnt-recognise-my-external-hard-drive/244963#244963

Comment: You said the partitions are “detected” on a Linux machine and a MacBook Air.  Can you *mount* those partitions on the MBA and can you mount the FAT partition on Windows and/or Linux?

Comment: Also see this answer for assistance:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/296316/119271

Comment: @Allan Yes, on the MBA I could mount all the partitions and carry out all normal tasks. The FAT partition was also mounted on the Windows machine.